# Combining regular expressions for email scraping

Tags: python, regex, email

I have two expressions: 

1. `(\w+)[\s\(]at[\s\)](\w+)\sdot\s(\w+)\sdot\sedu`
2. `(\w+)[\s\(]at[\s\)](\w+)\.(\w+)\.edu`

The first one identifies :

> csk at cs dot xyz dot edu 
>   csk(at)cs dot xyz dot edu

The second one identifies :

> csk at cs.xyz.edu 
>   csk(at)cs.xyz.edu

How do I combine the above two? I also want to include **@** in it, what I did was :

`(\w+)[\s\(][/at/@][\s\)](\w+)\sdot\s(\w+)\sdot\sedu`

but it is not working. Can some one please help? I have lot of formats to cover but dont want to write each regular expression explicitly.

Comment: i found a neat site , to try regex -http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the varying patterns inside a non-capturing group separated by `|` logical OR operator.

```
(\w+)[\s\(](?:at|@)[\s\)](\w+)(?:\sdot\s(\w+)\sdot\sedu|\.(\w+)\.edu)
```

Add anchors if necessary.

```
^(\w+)[\s\(](?:at|@)[\s\)](\w+)(?:\sdot\s(\w+)\sdot\s|\.(\w+)\.)edu$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hK1uH1/6)

Comment: The output I'm getting is:<br/>`[('csk', 'cs', 'xyz', ''), ('csk', 'cs', 'xyz', ''), ('csk', 'cs', '', 'xyz'), ('csk', 'cs', '', 'xyz'), ('csk', 'cs', '', 'xyz'), ('csk', 'cs', 'xyz', '')]`. How do I get rid of the empty spaces?

Comment: I cannot use filter(None,array) since the elements in the list are tuples.

Comment: @CSK try this `[tuple(filter(None, i)) for i in lst]`

Comment: I'm using `for t in tuple: if t != '':` and it's working. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

`[/at/@]` does not match what you think it does.  `[...]` denotes a character set, so that part is matching the individual characters `/`, `a`, `t`, or `@`.

In order to match either `at` or `@`, you will need to use:

```
(?:at|@)
```

Here is a reference on Python's [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).